# Need circular cropping functionality instead of rectangular

Tags: android, crop, geometry

I have been searching the net for this but couldn't find the any help.

I want to capture an Image by invoking camera and want to crop it. But the thing is instead of RECTANGULAR crop( given in image) tool I need a CIRCULAR one (second image).

Note: First image shows -  crop rectangular area and then using some other function displays it in circular fashion.
while image two shows - crop image in circular shape.

[image]

[image]

All I found on net was to crop using this rectangular tool and then display the image in circular view. (But I want to crop in circular form)

What I am doing in onActivityResult function is-

```
             case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:         
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) 
                {               
                    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                      //this method convert the rectangular cropped image to circular display.
                    GraphicsUtil gu= new GraphicsUtil();
                    Bitmap output = gu.getCircleBitmap(photo,16);
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(output);

                  }

                File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
                if (f.exists()) f.delete();
                break;
```

Code for GraphicsUtil function is as below -

```
public Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xffff0000;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth((float) 4);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }
```

So you can see. Image is cropped rectangular then passed to a function which display it in circular fashion.
 I want that image is cropped in circular way by CROP_FROM_CAMERA intent only without using GraphicUtil function.

Comment: If you have a bitmap with the image cropped as you want, what more are you asking? Where are you wanting the crop to occur?

Comment: I edited the question in order to be more clear. Hope you get what I want to ask.

Comment: So you want the built-in cropping tool to have different functionality?

Comment: can we achieve a transparent background with this technique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since different manufacturers implement their own interfaces for camera, the first method below will not work in all cases. For example, it worked on my Nexus S running stock 2.3.6 and not on my Galaxy Nexus on stock 4.3. Anyway, if you want to be able to crop your image in a circular fashion from the default crop action call it in the following way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setData(imageUri); // Uri to the image you want to crop
intent.putExtra("outputX", Constants.PROFILE_PICTURE_SIZE);
intent.putExtra("outputY", Constants.PROFILE_PICTURE_SIZE);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("circleCrop", new String(""));
intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
File cropImageFile = new File(CROP_IMAGE_PATH); // Path to save the cropped image
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(cropImageFile));
startActivityForResult(intent, CROP); // CROP = Code to track the result in  onActivityResult
```

This should start the default crop app that will look like this:
[image: Circular cropping]

If you've read this post by [commonsware](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html), you know that this will not always work. I suggest including one of the libraries from his post. The first one from [lvillani](https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage) is the CropImage activity extracted AOSP. Include the library and make call it with an intent similar to the one above. Make sure you include the circleCrop param in the intent.

Comment: Thanks buddy. That's exactly what I needed :). Here +50 points for you.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the role of "Constants.PROFILE_PICTURE_SIZE" in line intent.putExtra("outputX", Constants.PROFILE_PICTURE_SIZE);

Comment: @User42 in my project, that constant is an integer with a value of 600 (pixels)

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699496/cropped-image-size-in-android-is-constant

Comment: @User42 just posted an answer. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
    BitmapShader shader;
    shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShader(shader);

    RectF rect = new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height);

    Bitmap circularBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(circularBitmap);

    canvas.drawArc(rect, 0, 360, true, paint);
```

now circularBitmap is holding the circular image.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet, but it should work...

I will assume you can get the image from the camera. Once you have that image, you can proceed as follows.

Get a `Canvas` to draw on a new bitmap. Create a `Path` object and call `addCircle`. Call `clipPath` on the `Canvas` passing your circular `Path`. Now draw the  camera image to the `Canvas` and it should only draw inside the clipping area. Unlock the `Canvas` and use the new `Bitmap` to save out whatever type of image you want. Dispose of whatever resources as appropriate.