# Cropped Image size in Android is constant

Tags: android, image, width, crop

I am cropping an image in circular fashion and using below code while creating the intent

```
    intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
```

Since I am using outputX = 200, I am getting width and height of every cropped image as 200 and 200 , no matter how much I zoom-in or zoom out.

Below shown both images have different zoom ratio but still return same height and width.

```
 width  = bitmap.getWidth();
```

[image]

[image]

Can someone please tell me what parameter should I use in line

```
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
```

so that I get the TRUE width and height(not the 200 in each case) of cropped image.

Comment: Did you removed those 2 paramenters(outputx,outputy) and then tried???

Comment: Yes tried. But for some values of width and height it worked fine but for some values it crashed. 
Means when I zoomed in more [image 2 in question](width and height approx 280) it worked fine but when zoom in was less [image 1 in question](width and height approx > 300) , application just closes without any error or warning.

Comment: Yes because it cannot such huge amount of data. Are you getting OutOfMemory error for it. After cropping it, what are u doing with it???? Setting it to image view???

Comment: Yes. after cropping I am setting it to an image view. No such error is being displayed in logCat. It just closes silently.

Comment: Any suggestion how can I avoid this situation. I mean handling of large data. Btw earlier this was not that problem. no matter how much you zoom in or zoom out. it was displayed on imageview peacefully with width and height 200 each.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't know this was the issue when I answered the your [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204619/need-circular-cropping-functionality-instead-of-rectangular/19640905) question. I believe the answer you are looking for should be:

```
intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("scale", false);
```

Make sure you set the parameter scale to false. It defaults to true.

PS Since Android is open source and the camera + crop app is a part of the OS, all I am doing is reading the source. The file you should be looking at is [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.2_r1/com/android/camera/CropImage.java). Check out variable mScale to see how the parameter is being used.

Comment: setting scale parameter to false leads to weird behaviour. Not working as expected.

Comment: Can you tell me what happens? What device and OS are you using? I will try on a similar one.